# Check which template was used to create Excel workbook

Tags: vsto

Is it possible to check whether particular template was used for creation of the workbook?

In word I have a piece of code:

```
string templateUsed = document.get_AttachedTemplate().FullName;
```

or

```
var templateName = document.BuiltInDocumentProperties[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyTemplate].Value.ToString();
```

I want to execute a piece of code if working ONLY on my template, for instance:

```
workbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load("PathToMyColors.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.TemplatesPath similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799971/how-to-get-excel-template-path-from-vsto-project/9841415#9841415)