# How to find out the installation-directory / path from COM-AddIn

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-office, add-in, comaddin

I've got a List of COM-AddIns from Excel and want to find out the installation-path of the AddIns, but the object "Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn" only have the following Properties:

```
Application
Connect
Creator
Description
Guid
Object
Parent
ProgId
```

And the Property Object is "Nothing/Null".

Is there a way to use the Interop? Or do i use the guid and search in the registry?

Comment: You mean you are getting the listof Excel COM-Addins through the program, and you need to find its installation path?

Comment: Right. I get the COM-AddIns through the Excel-Interop in VSTO-Project.

Comment: Check this existing post [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886957/find-install-directory-and-working-directory-of-vsto-outlook-addin-or-any-offic)

Comment: Its not solve my Problem... the first Answers said how to create a VSTO and set the installationpath and the last answer said how to get the path of the executing assembly, but i want to know the location of every installed COM-AddIn.