# Read custom file path from VSTO plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, office-interop, excel-addins

I have an excel plugin where I want to read an xml file on form load from a config folder, but I can't figure out how to read from that folder after I deploy the application.

On the excel ribbon, when the user clicks a button to open my plugin, on form load, I want to read from a specified directory.  I am deploying the application with ClickOnce and using VS 2017.  I set the xml file build to Content and set Copy to output directory as Always.  When I deploy, it puts the xml file in some ClickOnce dll folder when the user installs it.

Comment: Does this help? [Find Install directory and working directory of VSTO Outlook Addin; or any Office Addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886957/find-install-directory-and-working-directory-of-vsto-outlook-addin-or-any-offic)

Answer (score 0):

Try `InstallDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;` at startup of you plugin.

In `ThisAddIn_Startup` or in your ribbon constructor.